# How do I reveal an element when an input[type=date] receives a value?

Tags: html, jquery, css, forms, date

I'm trying to build a progressive form but can't find a solution to reveal additional form fields when a standard date picker has received a value. All solutions I've found involve date validation or conditional logic that goes beyond my requirements and understanding.

I've had success revealing elements with :checked for radio inputs but is there something like this that would work for date inputs? jQuery is also acceptable as I'm already using it to restrict past dates from being selected.

```js
$(function(){
 var dtToday = new Date();
 var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
 var day = dtToday.getDate();
 var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
 if(month < 10)
 month = '0' + month.toString();
 if(day < 10)
 day = '0' + day.toString();
 var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
 $('#date').attr('min', maxDate);
});
```

```css
.when, .form {display:none;}
input:checked ~ .when {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Are you sending or receiving?</h4>
<input type="radio" id="sender" name="clienttype"><label for="sender">Sending</label>
<input type="radio" id="receiver" name="clienttype"><label for="receiver">Receiving</label>

<div class="when">
 <h4>When?</h4>
 <input type="date" id="date" name="Date">
</div>

<div class="form">
 Extra form fields go here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try jQuery `change()` event to get the value when date is changed

```
$('#date').change(function() {
    let date = $(this).val();
    console.log(date);
});
```